# Spring Web Flow constants for scopes

Tags: spring-webflow

Are there any constants for Spring Web Flow to use instead of "view", "conversation", etc... when defining the **@Scope** annotation for scoped beans?

The closest thing I've found is the **ScopeType** enumeration which has no use in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Scope annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html) doc says:

```
    Scope means the lifecycle of an instance, such as singleton, prototype, 
    and so forth. Scopes provided out of the box in Spring may be referred 
    to using the SCOPE_* constants available in via ConfigurableBeanFactory 
    and WebApplicationContext interfaces.
```

The constants available in these [bean definitions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/constant-values.html#org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON) are:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory
    public static final String  SCOPE_PROTOTYPE     "prototype"
    public static final String  SCOPE_SINGLETON     "singleton"
```

The constants available in WebApplicationContext:

```
    org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext
    public static final String  SCOPE_APPLICATION   "application"
    public static final String  SCOPE_GLOBAL_SESSION    "globalSession"
    public static final String  SCOPE_REQUEST   "request"
    public static final String  SCOPE_SESSION   "session"
```

Comment: I already know the constants for common Spring scopes but what I'm looking for are the ones specific for Spring Web Flow

Answer (score 0):

Spring webflow provides 5 different scopes for variables defined in a flow.
These

From the [Spring WebFlow reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/pdf/spring-webflow-reference.pdf):

## 3.9. Variable Scopes

Web Flow can store variables in one of several scopes:

#### Flow Scope

Flow scope gets allocated when a flow starts and destroyed when the flow ends. With the default
implementation, any objects stored in flow scope need to be Serializable.

#### View Scope

View scope gets allocated when a view-state enters and destroyed when the state exits. View scope
is only referenceable from within a view-state. With the default implementation, any objects stored
in view scope need to be Serializable.

#### Request Scope

Request scope gets allocated when a flow is called and destroyed when the flow returns.

#### Flash Scope

Flash scope gets allocated when a flow starts, cleared after every view render, and destroyed when the
flow ends. With the default implementation, any objects stored in flash scope need to be Serializable.

#### Conversation Scope

Conversation scope gets allocated when a top-level flow starts and destroyed when the top-level
flow ends. Conversation scope is shared by a top-level flow and all of its subflows. With the default
implementation, conversation scoped objects are stored in the HTTP session and should generally be Serializable to account for typical session replication.

The scope to use is often determined contextually, for example depending on where a variable is defined
-- at the start of the flow definition (flow scope), inside a a view state (view scope), etc. In other cases,
for example in EL expressions and Java code, it needs to be specified explicitly. Subsequent sections
explain how this is done.